# Serve static pages & REST services with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed a Spring application that serves Spring MVC REST services. Now I want to implement Angularjs in to the webapp directory of my Spring application. The problem is that I don't know how to correctly configure this.

What I want to achieve:

- /api/... = URL that serves REST services over Spring MVC such as localhost:8080/api/user/1
- /... = URL that contains static html pages such as localhost:8080/index.html

Also I would like that index.html will be loaded by default.

Currently I'm using following configuration which works but it doesn't load index.html by default. But I don't know if this is really the way I should configure static pages within the Spring Container:

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.eerra" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Tell Spring what to treat as resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/resources/ang2/app/"/>
```

With the current configuration everything is working but when I try to point my browser to localhost:8080/ then a 404 not found appears instead of loading the index.html file. When i try with localhost:8080/index.html then everything works.

Can somebody point me in to the right direction how to configure such a setup?

Below you can see my debug.log. Problem here seems to be following:

**Did not find handler method for [/]**

So I guess that the DispatcherServlet is trying to map the path to a controller. But I don't know how I can avoid this.

```
21:55:04.896 [qtp581501261-25] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 314/314
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST / on AsyncHttpConnection@f908897,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=9,c=0},r=1
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||/ @ o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/charms/Documents/Intellij%20Projects/cardkeeper/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/Users/charms/Documents/Intellij%20Projects/cardkeeper/src/main/webapp/
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=||/ @ o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/charms/Documents/Intellij%20Projects/cardkeeper/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/Users/charms/Documents/Intellij%20Projects/cardkeeper/src/main/webapp/
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@70799896
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - session=null
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet |/|null -> spring
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=springSecurityFilterChain->spring
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - call filter springSecurityFilterChain
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/favicon.ico*'
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/**'
21:55:04.897 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
21:55:04.898 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/api/**'
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.PublicInvocationEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /]
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - call servlet spring
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Bound request context to thread: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ (GET /)@604241542 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@2403fe86]]
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/]
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@12440d38] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
21:55:04.899 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@c518734] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - No handler mapping found for [/]
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@3c836d3d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/] are [/**]
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/] are {}
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@6abe6713] and 1 interceptor
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@7a614724]
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@885cb41]
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
21:55:04.912 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Ignoring invalid resource path []
21:55:04.913 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - No matching resource found - returning 404
21:55:04.913 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
21:55:04.913 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ [GET /]@604241542 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@2403fe86]]
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[spring]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[15ms]; status=[OK]
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[spring]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[15ms]; status=[OK]
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
21:55:04.914 [qtp581501261-25 - /] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /  404 handled=true
21:55:04.915 [qtp581501261-25] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@7cee85c5{l(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51001)<->r(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@f908897,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=0,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=9,c=0},r=1}
21:55:04.915 [qtp581501261-25] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - filled 0/0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem the following way.

- First I have changed the path from the servlet-mapping to /api/*. This resultet that I had to adjust the path in the MVC Controllers from @RequestMapping("/api/role") to @RequestMapping("/role"). Otherwise the URL would have responded to /api/api/role.
- Then I have integrated urlrewrite http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/. I'm using Maven so I added it to the pom.xml. I did this because the mvc:resource mapping directive seems only to work when the DispatcherServlet is used. And this was what I wanted to disable for my static html pages.
- Then I have added the filter to the web.xml file and created a urlrewrite.xml file in the WEB-INF directory as seen below.
- With urlrewrite I could set a condition that excludes /api/** (directory with my Spring MVC based REST Controllers) but rewrites anything else from /** to /resources/ang2/app directory (my angularjs directory).
- Also I have deleted the mvc:resource directive from applicationContext.xml.

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Setup urlrewrite filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>WARN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring related section -->
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**urlrewrite.xml**

```
<!-- Use urlrewritefilter to redirect / requests to angularjs directory -->
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
<rule>
    <!-- exclude everything in /api/** directory -->
    <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">/api/**</condition>
    <!-- everything else from / is redirected to the angularjs directory -->
    <from>/**</from>
    <to>/resources/ang2/app/$1</to>
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined a welcome file in your web.xml?

For example

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

where index.html is a file in your project root folder.

Comment: Yes, but this didn't do the trick. Exactly the same thing happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved, as you advised, prefixing the rest api pattern managed by Spring.

The only difference is that I didn't used the url rewriter because all my angular files are deployed in the root of the web app, so directly accessible.

My Angular project is actually in a different folder, as a different module and is added during the war build with this configuration:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3</version>
     <configuration>
         <webResources>
             <resource>
                 <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/ANGULAR-PROJECT-NAME
             </resource>
         </webResources>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

like explained [here](https://github.com/trecloux/yeoman-maven-plugin). Hope this helps, regards.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that ResourceHttpRequestHandler which is registered by <mvc:resource> doesnt resolve to foo/index.html when requesting foo/

A parameter that would enable this behavior would be nice.